# How to bind a DataGrid inside a Listview in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datagrid

I have the following listview, it has two main sections a `<table>` with labels inside it and a `datagrid`. I populate the  fields using a Datatable but I have no idea how to bind the datagrid.

```
<asp:ListView 
ID="ListView1" 
    runat="server">
<LayoutTemplate>
   <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" >
    <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
       </div>
</LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Panel runat="server">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
               <cc1:SWCLabel runat="server" 
                   Text='<%# Eval("field1") %>'
               />
             </td>
             <td>
                 <cc1:SWCLabel runat="server" 
                     Text='<%# Eval("field2") %>'
                 />
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

  <asp:DataGrid ID="datagrid_1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundColumn  DataField="col1" HeaderText="column1 ">
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn  DataField="col2" HeaderText="column2 ">
            </asp:BoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </cc1:SWCDataGrid>
  </asp:Panel>                            
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

My codebehind:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
// GET DATA
// . . .
ListView1.DataSource = table;
ListView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: The DataBind above works only when no datagrid is declared in the aspx.

Comment: If you want to bind to DataGrid why not set datagrid_1.DataSource = table; instead of ListView1.DataSource = table;

Comment: Because I also need to bind the other fields. datagrid_1 is just on of the listview fields.

Answer (score 0):

because ur gridview is in item template,
do it on 'item data bound' event of listview.

Comment: Could you try to improve your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help if you gave us some idea about the structure of your data.  So you are trying to display a DataGrid for each element of the ListView.  To me that means that each element of your ListView has a set of related data which needs to display in its own DataGrid.  To do that, in addition to your Listview DataBind code, you would need something like:  (in VB, should be easy to make into C#)

```
Protected Sub ListView1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemDataBound

        Dim theDataGrid As DataGrid = e.Item.FindControl("datagrid_1")

        Dim itemData As DataTable = GetTheItemData(e.Item.DataItem)

        theDataGrid.DataSource = itemData 
        theDataGrid.DataBind()          

 End Sub
```

This handler will be called each time an Item of your list view is DataBound.  Each time it gets the related data of that item, and uses it to populate the DataGrid for that item.